# What do the 502 errors coming from /_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis mean?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, fuzzing

I'm running a Django application on Google App Engine and I noticed logs coming from /_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis  that result in a 502
[image: The Log]
Does anyone know what this means and where it comes from? I can not find anything about fuzzing in the GAE docs.

Comment: Hi Max, please let me know if the answer posted was useful for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing for information about the error message, I found that Cloud Endpoints v1 is no longer supported and was shut down on August 2, 2018.

As recommended, here is the link to [Migrating to Cloud Endpoints Frameworks version 2.0](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/migrating).

In the case of the 502 error code, App Engine may take a few minutes to reply to queries satisfactorily. If you send a request and receive an HTTP 502 response, wait a minute and try again.

App Engine terminated the program because it ran out of memory, according to an error code 502 with BAD GATEWAY in the message. Only 600MB of memory is available for the application container in the basic App Engine flexible VM.

If the error message was regarding a bad gateway, here is how to [troubleshoot the 502 error code](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/troubleshoot-response-errors#error_message_bad_gateway).

Comment: Hey, I am not using Cloud Endpoints but a django app with the drf framework.
The 502 error code seems to be coming from a tool on the GAE platform and I was just curious to see what it does. I am not trying to fix this because it does not interfere with my operations.